# "Let's go to a mountain" vs "let's go to the mountain."

Tags: expressions

You can say:

> Let's go to the beach.

But I've never heard anyone say:

> Let's go to the mountain.

So I wonder if it should be:

> Let's go to a mountain.

Is that acceptable?

Is it acceptable to say the following?

> "Yes, we can go on a trip. Too bad I can't think of any place right
>   now."
>
> "How about the mountain?"

Perhaps this is more *natural*?

> "Yes, we can go on a trip. Too bad I can't think of any place right
>   now."
>
> "How about a mountain?"

Comment: Does the title exactly match with the intended question?

Comment: @Shaona Bose OK, edited.

Comment: You can certainly say *Let’s go to the mountain*, so the premise is flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing different modes of idiomatic expressions.

"Let's go to the beach" is used to indicate a *type* of landscape characterized by typical activities. It does not refer to *any particular individual beach.* It refers to the *concept* of *a beach area*.

Therefore, you don't hear people say "let's go to the mountain" as an equivalent expression, because *that* phrase does not mean the *concept* of a mountain landscape. When we say "go to the mountain," we are always referring to a specific mountain. For example, if we have agreed that we are going to Mount Everest, then we can say, "let's go to the mountain." If, on the other hand, we want to say that we just want to go to a general landscape of mountains, in the same way we would say we want to go to a general landscape of *beach*, we say "let's go to *THE* mountains." Note that this is plural.

Comment: John, so "If the mountain won't come to Muhammad then *Muhammad must go to the mountain*." may be wrong because the mountain is unspecified?

Comment: @Carlo_R. "The mountain" is metaphorical and refers to the situation under discussion, so (a) it's different because it's a metaphor; (b) it's already been referenced.